# Consulta SQL dependiendo del role de usuario

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día
Necesito obtener los deudores de una comunidad, para iniciar sesión en la comunidad puede ser un superadmin, que puede ver todos los registros, pero si inicia sesión como un administrador de una comunidad, solo puede ver los registros de esa comunidad.
Tengo la siguiente sql:

```
public function getReservas(){
// Obtenemos el ID del usuario actual
$id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_username'];

// Verificamos si el usuario es superadmin
$superadmin = $_SESSION['role_id'];

// Si es superadmin, mostramos todas las dependencias
if ($superadmin == 1) {
  $sql = "SELECT r.id_reserva, r.id_depto, r.id_lugar, r.fechaHoraInicio, r.fechaHoraTermino, r.valor, r.nota, r.estado, r.id_comunidad,
        d.id_depto, d.nro_depto
        FROM reservas r
        LEFT JOIN deptos d ON r.id_depto = d.id_depto";
} else {
  $sql = "SELECT r.id_reserva, r.id_depto, r.id_lugar, r.fechaHoraInicio, r.fechaHoraTermino, r.valor, r.nota, r.estado, r.id_comunidad,
  d.id_depto, d.nro_depto
  FROM reservas r
  LEFT JOIN deptos d ON r.id_depto = d.id_depto
  WHERE id_comunidad = (SELECT id_comunidad FROM admins WHERE role_id = > 1)";
}
$data = $this->selectAll($sql);
return $data;
```

}

[image: adjunto imagen de estructura de la tabla admins, reservas y comunidades]

Comment: la consulta no obtiene datos por que tienes un `return $data;` en medio de un archivo php que a su vez tiene un funcion publica ... extrala organizacion del codigo... me gustaria saber por que no te revienta ... ya que esa forma en la que presentas el codigo no es funcional...

Comment: Puede salir en una sola consulta, supongo que tienes una tabla de usuarios ¿se relaciona con admins?.

Comment: Dudo que sea útil utilizar `AND role_id == 1` (cosa que tiene una sintaxis incorrecta) y el otro que tienes de `AND role_id >= 1`, ya que eso lo debes obtener desde antes para validar tus condicionales, algo como `if($_SESSION['role_id']==1){$sql="...";}else{$sql="...";}`.  La parte verdadera de tu condicional será igual que el código que pusiste primero (sin el `WHERE d.id_comunidad = a.id_comunidad AND role_id == 1"`). Y en la parte falsa debes OBTENER primero el id de la comunidad de ese usuario activo para poder ponerlo como variable en la condición de tu `WHERE`

Comment: @Sal solo tengo una tabla admins, no necesito usuarios.

Comment: @Marcos Tienes razón, ya modifique el código, voy a editar la pregunta, ya muestra los datos si es el superadmin, pero no cuando es un admin

Comment: @Ominous voy a editar la pregunta

Comment: @Marcos, agregue imagen de la estructura de las tablas.

Comment: @Marcos  A ver, como me explico, es un sistema de comunidades, la idea es que yo como superadmin, pueda ver todos los registros del sistema, y se configura un admin para cada comunidad que ingrese al sistema, ahora ese administrador puede ingresar mas administradores pero con distintos permisos, y esos admin solo pueden ver, editar y eliminar registros según sus permisos, por ende las reservas pueden ser muchas en una sola comunidad, no se si me expliqué bien, espero que me entiendas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149454/discussion-between-claudio-gonzalez-and-marcos).

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando tu código actual y solo en el caso de que NO sea `superadmin` bastaría con agregar:

- Un `JOIN` entre las tablas `reservas` y `admins`
- Un `WHERE` indicando que el `id` del admin es el del usuario que inició sesión.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
public function getReservas() {
    // Obtenemos el ID del usuario actual
    $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_username'];

    // Verificamos si el usuario es superadmin
    $superadmin = $_SESSION['role_id'];

    // Si es superadmin, mostramos todas las dependencias
    if ($superadmin == 1) {
        $sql = "SELECT r.id_reserva, r.id_depto, r.id_lugar, r.fechaHoraInicio, r.fechaHoraTermino, r.valor, r.nota, r.estado, r.id_comunidad,
            d.id_depto, d.nro_depto
            FROM reservas r
            LEFT JOIN deptos d ON r.id_depto = d.id_depto";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT r.id_reserva, r.id_depto, r.id_lugar, r.fechaHoraInicio, r.fechaHoraTermino, r.valor, r.nota, r.estado, r.id_comunidad,
            d.id_depto, d.nro_depto
            FROM reservas r
            LEFT JOIN deptos d ON r.id_depto = d.id_depto
            LEFT JOIN admins a ON r.id_comunidad = a.id_comunidad
            WHERE a.id = $id_usuario";
    }
    $data = $this->selectAll($sql);
    return $data;
}
```

Otra opción sería modificar el `WHERE` que actualmente utilizas así:

```php
$sql = "SELECT ...
    WHERE r.id_comunidad = (SELECT id_comunidad FROM admins WHERE id = ".$id_usuario.")";
```

Y finalmente, como en la variable de sesión ya tenes el `id_comunidad`, podrías simplemente hacer:

```php
$sql = "SELECT ...
    WHERE r.id_comunidad = " . $_SESSION['id_comunidad'];
```

---

#### Comentario:

Para que los `JOIN` y/o el `WHERE` sean más eficientes sería bueno que agregues indices a los campos que relacionan las tablas entre sí.

Ejemplo:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `reservas` ADD KEY `id_comunidad` (`id_comunidad`);
ALTER TABLE `admins` ADD KEY `id_comunidad` (`id_comunidad`);
# etc.
```

Comment: Gracias @Marcos, el asunto es que creo que a esa parte de la consulta no llega id_comunidad, provee, igual como me indicas.  Con los dos where, agregue, los indices a todas las tablas con id_comunidad. Inicio sesión como superadmin y funciona bien, pero como admin, da error de dataTable, eso me hace pensar que esa consulta falta algún campo.
Error:
DataTables warning: table id=tblReservas - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: Hola @ClaudioGonzalez. El mensaje _"Invalid JSON response"_ indica que la respuesta obtenida no es un JSON. Lo mas seguro es que este ocurriendo un error. ¿Podes entrar [al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149454/discussion-between-claudio-gonzalez-and-marcos) asi me pasas la consulta que esta usando?